# Is there a way to return a username in one cell when a date has been populated in another cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a worksheet that asks the user to confirm if they reviewed the contents. When "Yes" is entered in D23, I would then like to put the "Username" into C23. I'd prefer not to use VBA as I have other code in there and I'm not a good enough to add more code without messing things up. I found the following:

```
Formulas/Define Name

Name:  User
Scope:  Workbook
RefersTo:  =get.workspace(26)
```

Then, in some cell, if you enter:  `=User`   It should return the current user.

Which gives me the username when I input `=User` into a cell so I was trying to create a formula to put `=User` into the cell where I want the username but I get errors. Has anyone a simple IF statement that will get me to where I want to go?

Comment: Are you able to get the username in any cell?

Comment: Kaiser, yes I can get the function above to return the username into a cell when I type =User, what I am trying to do is get the username in automatically - hope I'm explaining that well!

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

If the user name is in cell A1, you can copy the formula on cell C23:

```
=IF(D23="Yes",A1,"")
```

Comment: Although OP probably needs to evaluate it once and store the result, instead of storing a formula that updates depending on who is viewing the document.

Comment: This works, however when the next person opens the book the original name is replaced. is there a way to lock a name in once it is populated?

Comment: You can set up a Macro to do that (it can't be done by formulas), if it's that simple you don't need to know about VBA, just use the "Record Macro" Button on the Developer Tab